# Recursive function that separates adjacent identical characters by a space

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

How to write a recursive function that takes a string argument and returns a string where adjacent identical characters are separated by a space?

I wrote a non-recursive function that does what I want:

```
def space_adj(istr):
    new_str = ''
    delimiter = ' '
    for i, ch in enumerate(istr[:len(istr)-1]): 
        if ch == istr[i+1]:
            new_str += ch + delimiter 
        else:
            new_str += ch
    new_str += istr[-1]
    return new_str
```

I want it to do this:

```
>>> space_adj('abcdeffghhh')
'abcdef fgh h h'
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to replace a non-recursive function with a recursive one?

Comment: Since strings are immutable I'm not sure it makes much sense to do this recursively (unless you 'cheat' and use lists, then it might perform a bit better than the non-recursive solution). Is this for educational purposes only?

Comment: Non-recursive version using `itertools.groupby`: `''.join(' '.join(g) for k, g in groupby('abcdeffghhh'))`

Comment: Yes, I'm learning recursion in class and this is one of the practice problems I'm stuck on.

Comment: If you really want to convert this to recursive, have you at least tried something?

Comment: I tried figuring out how to do it without recursion (successfully) so I could possibly figure out how do it with recursion but I'm still stuck.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh If we start suggesting something not related to the question, there's many more answers. What about regexp for example: `re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1 \1', 'aabcdeffghhh')` ?

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs?

Comment: yes, your answer was the one i liked the best.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really necessary to make that recursive, but it can be done like this:

```
delimiter = " "

def space_adj(istr):
    if len(istr) < 2:  # The end-condition for the recursion
        return istr
    result = space_adj(istr[:-1])  # Get result for the shorter string with recursion
    if istr[-1] == istr[-2]:
        return result + delimiter + istr[-1]
    else:
        return result + istr[-1]
```

Note the shorter syntax `istr[:-1]` for your `istr[:len(istr)-1]`.

Just for mentioning an unrelated alternative: you can do this with one regular expression substitution:

```
import re
def space_adj(istr):
    return re.sub(r"(\w)(?=\1)", r"\1 ", istr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can design a recursive function using typical base and inductive case(s) like this -

```
def space_adj (s, delim = " "):
  # base case: one char or less
  if len(s) < 2:
    return s
  # inductive case 1: at least two chars
  elif s[0] == s[1]:
    return s[0] + delim + space_adj(s[1:], delim)
  # inductive case 2: at least two unmatching chars
  else:
    return s[0] + space_adj(s[1:], delim)
```

Python uses symbolic syntaxes for many basic operations, but I think it hurts program readability overall -

```
def first (x):
  return x[0]

def second (x):
  return x[1]

def tail (x):
  return x[1:]

def space_adj (s, delim = " "):
  if len(s) < 2:
    return str
  elif first(s) == second(s):
    return first(s) + delim + space_adj(tail(s), delim)
  else:
    return first(s) + space_adj(tail(s), delim)
```

Output for each version of the program is identical -

```
print(space_adj("abcdeffghhh"))
# "abcdef fgh h h"

print(space_adj("a"))
# "a"

print(space_adj(""))
# ""
```

---

Or try using a helper function to break the problem down into smaller parts. Below we had to write two functions instead of just one, but each one is

- easier to write
- easier to read
- easier to test/debug/maintain

```
def join (a, b, delim = " "):
  if a == b:
    return a + delim
  else:
    return a

def space_adj (s):
  if len(s) < 2:
    return s
  else:
    return join(s[0], s[1]) + space_adj(s[1:])

print(space_adj("abcdeffghhh"))
# "abcdef fgh h h"
```

---

Recursion is a functional heritage and so it's best to learn recursion in its natural context. Above you can see `space_adj` is just a simple machine to do this -

```
space_adj("abcde")
    = join("a","b")
        + join("b","c")
            + join("c","d")
                + join("d","e")
                    + "e"
```

This means `space_adj` itself can be generic function if we make `join` a parameter. Below we give a more specific name to our join, `space_between_same`. And now we have a generic `joiner` function -

```
def space_between_same (a, b):
  if a == b:
    return a + " "
  else:
    return a

def joiner (s, join = space_between_same):
  if len(s) < 2:
    return s
  else:
    return join(s[0], s[1]) + joiner(s[1:], join)

print(joiner("abcdeffghhh"))
# "abcdef fgh h h"
```

Now that we can specify *how* to join, we can see the capability and flexibility of higher-order functions -

```
joiner("CamelToTitleCase", lambda a, b: a + " " if b.isupper() else a)
# "Camel To Title Case"

joiner("CamelToSnakeCase", lambda a, b: a.lower() + "_" if b.isupper() else a.lower())
# "camel_to_snake_case"

joiner("reemoveed duplicatees", lambda a, b: "" if a == b else a))
# "removed duplicates"

joiner([ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ], lambda a, b: [] if a == b else [a]))
# [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Above, `space_between_same` hard-codes the `" "` delimiter. We can make another higher-order function `between_same` to make the delimiter user-configurable -

```
def between_same (delim = ""):
  def join (a, b):
    if a == b:
      return a + delim
    else:
      return a
  return join

def joiner (s, join = between_same(" ")):
  if len(s) < 2:
    return s
  else:
    return join(s[0], s[1]) + joiner(s[1:], join)

print(joiner("abcdeffghhh")) # default
# "abcdef fgh h h"

print(joiner("abcdeffghhh", between_same("=")))
# "abcdef=fgh=h=h"
```

Breaking the problem down in this way yielded a very different program, but as you can see, we can direct our program to many desirable outcomes with almost zero complexity.

---

Related: `joiner` above is similar but not identical to a [*fold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question [python-3.x], let's use a Python-3-ism:

```
def space_adj(istr):
    if not istr:
        return istr

    first, *second_on = istr

    if not second_on:
        return first

    second, *_ = second_on

    return first + ['', ' '][first == second] + space_adj(second_on)
```

One trick here is that we're treating the argument as a *sequence*, not specifically a *str*.  On recursion, the argument becomes a *list*, but it's still a sequence so everything works.